# C# showing wrong output, but other output based on it is correct

Tags: c#

I'm having a problem with the last line for "deduction".
it's a program to calculate an employee's net pay. every output is coming up as the teacher wants except for the deductions. when ran it's showing "292.22" instead of "368.72" with input being: hours = 48.55, rate = 25.50, and dependents = 3.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Program5
{
    class NetPay
        {
        static double hours, rate, dependents;
        const double TAXRATE = .23;
        const double DEPENDENTS = 25.50;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetInput();
            Calculations();
        }
        static void GetInput()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter hours worked: ");
            hours = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter hourly rate: ");
            rate = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Enter number of dependents: ");
            dependents = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        static void Calculations()
        {
            double gross, netPay, deduction;

            Console.WriteLine("\nHourse Worked:\t\t\t\t\t   {0:c}", hours);
            Console.WriteLine("Hourly Rate:\t\t\t\t\t   {0:c}", rate);
            Console.WriteLine("Dependents:\t\t\t\t\t\t{0}", dependents);

            if (hours > 40)
                gross = Math.Round((((hours - 40) * 1.5 ) * rate) + (40 *         rate), 2);    

            else
                gross = Math.Round(hours * rate, 2);            

            Console.WriteLine("Gross Pay:\t\t\t\t\t{0:c}", gross);

            dependents = Math.Round(dependents * DEPENDENTS, 2);
            gross = gross - dependents;

            deduction = Math.Round(gross * TAXRATE, 2);
            Console.WriteLine("Deductions:\t\t\t\t\t{0:c}", deduction);

            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\t\t\t---------");

            netPay = gross - deduction;
            Console.WriteLine("Net Pay:\t\t\t\t\t{0:c}", netPay);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using your numbers, the calculations do add up to 292.22, the only thing I can think of is perhaps you entered the wrong value in `const double DEPENDENTS = 25.50;`? (its the same as rate?). Also some tips: typo in the line `Hourse Worked:\t\t\t` and also consider doing `double gross, netPay, deduction, dependents_deduction;` and `dependents_deduction = Math.Round(dependents * DEPENDENTS, 2);` instead of modifying the global from the function.

Comment: Verify the teachers answer and verify the code you use.

Comment: Your tax deduction value actually comes from value `1,270.54`  (reduced by dependent's deduction value) instead of `1,347.04` (see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E9FzRH)). Check if your formula is actually right, as you're printed gross value before deduction.

Comment: You state that all the output looks correct except for the deduction, yet the net pay is based on the deduction amount. Are you sure net pay is correct? Because if you fix deduction, net pay is going to change.

Comment: I'm not confident with the formula I used for the if else statement